# Bash and shell script if statement to do something if a file is found

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement, grep

I have created a shell script to find a string within a text file, then display the results to the screen sorted through `grep`.

How could I surround this in an `if` statement so that if results are found then echo "Found!" and display the results afterwards else say "not found"?

I have gotten this far already by using various websites but I am stuck with this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
echo "enter name "
read search

echo "The String searched for "
grep -i $search $fileName

if [$search ????]
then
echo "Found!"

else
echo "Not Found!" 

fi
```

Comment: Note that `[` is a command name and needs to be separated from `$search` by a space.  Similarly, `]` must be the last argument to the `[` command; it too must be separated from the previous arguments to `[` by a space.

Comment: Additionally, even though `[[` is not a command but a keyword, it, too, must be surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `grep` call can be a part of the `if` statement:

```
if grep -q "$search" "$filename"; then
  echo "Found!"
else
  echo "Not Found!"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked like a dream :D im really beginning to enjoy bash scripting

Answer (score 0):

Check if `grep` returns a non-zero length string:

```
if [ -n "$(grep -i "$search" "$fileName")" ]; then
    echo "Found!"
else
    echo "Not Found!"
fi
```

Comment: You need to quote the command substitution to avoid a "too many arguments" error if `grep` outputs any white space (space on one line, multiple lines, etc).